# Salesforce Lightning component Issues in IE11

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, browser

Created a Lightning Component tab and added the tab to the App. when trying to open the app in IE11 - It throws the following error -

> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details.Unable to parse JSON response : Expected ':'

When trying to open the same Lightning component app in other browsers, it works fine without any issues. Is it browser issue or am I missing anything to make the app work in IE11. 
Note: It also works in Microsoft edge. The issue is only in IE11.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your lightning component code snippet?

Comment: It is an application not an individual LC. '.cmp' file or '.js'. which code you want me to share? it has many functions.

Comment: Can you use IE11 Dev Tool (F12 key will launch it) to get the network response for the last call to the endpoint /aura and post it here? I suspect there is a fatal error being sent back from the server as an HTML document that the Lightning client runtime is trying to parse as JSON.